# ODBC list heading not visible in R

Tags: r, list, visible

I have a user input to select the Category of interest and I would like to see if the chosen Category is in the database...

```
CategoryList <- sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM [OneView].[vDimProduct]")
```

The problem is `CategoryList$Category` is `NULL`.

So I would like to see if "Dog Food" %in% CategoryList$Category, which it is. however returns FALSE in R.

I am sure it is to do with:

```
$visible
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: What is `$visible`? How certain are you that the actual database table contains non-null entries in that column? Have you tried another simple test like `"select Category From [OneView].[vDimProduct] limit 10"` (or `"select top 10 ..."` if mssql) to see actual returns?

Comment: I actually can't find much about what $visible is despite much searching.
So I'd like to find out if someone can help.
There are ~100 Categories and there are no Nulls running the same query through MSSQL.

Comment: Where did you find `$visible`? It's not clear to me where that is found. Is it in `CategoryList`?

Comment: I found $visible at the bottom when i type in CategoryList

> CategoryList
$value
                         Category
1                   Aquatic Decor

115                 Small Pet Toy
116               Small Pet Treat
117                       Unknown

$visible
[1] FALSE

Comment: Well a workaround was just to convert CategoryList to a dataframe